# Add one spring-boot project as a jar to another project

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, jar

I have spring-boot project, which I packaged into JAR-file, and now I want to add this jar-file to another project, can I implement it?

Comment: That is not what you want... You don't want to include a massive executable jar as a dependency to another project. If you need the code move it to another dependency which isn't a Spring Boot application and include it in both projects.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the main class in your maven configuration or gradle configuration.
Also in any case exclude from scanning the main class and other classes that might cause conflicts.

Same applies for your dependencies in case of conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

(1) You must build Spring Boot application in JAR files (It's fat JAR, executable JAR file). This JAR file has G-A-V (GroupId, Artifact and Version). You must run Maven install command to add this JAR file to local repository.

(2) Use build tool (like Maven or Gradle) to add this file to dependency list in normal way.

Comment: Thank you, actually I built not "fat JAR", but "jar", because i don't need to run this jar, I need only my classes. I solved my question using this http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-build.html#howto-create-a-nonexecutable-jar reference.